# position relative and right property

Tags: html, css

I always thought by setting the div to relative and right 0 would position the div all the way to the right, if its parent was 100% width. Apparently I'm wrong and only absolute works like that. So is there no way to make it work with relative?

Comment: yup. it's `float:right;`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to set the parent to be relative, and it's child to absolute positioning.

```
.parent{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.right{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

​
Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/n9Vrv/

Answer (score 16):

There's a way to make it work to a relative.

One way is first to set the parent of the display to `inline-flex`.

Next, set the element (child) `position:relative; margin-left:auto; right:0;`.

Comment: ＋１  thr actual solution. It even uses `position:relative` on the child element. Huzzah for `flex`. Here’s a fiddle showing the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/tky8q9zt/

Comment: This is a valid solution, the only thing is I didn't need `right: 0` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there no way to make it work with relative?

Correct. Relative positioning is the position offset from where it would be with static positioning.

You need absolute positioning to position with respect to the edges of the containing block.