# Positioning an element from the right

Tags: css, css-position

So I have an `<aside>` with `position: relative` within a `<main>`.

I can position the `<aside>` just fine using `left: 25px;` or `top: 25px;` or `bottom: 25px;` but when I use `right: 25px`... no dice. It just sits there on the left side.

What am I missing?

I simply want the right hand side of the `<aside>` to be `25px` from the right hand side of the `<main>`.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ae48H.png)

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbwl8.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position relative and right property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919073/position-relative-and-right-property)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are wanting to do?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_right

Comment: Yes, it is,  The problem is that I need the <aside> to remain in normal page flow because I want the <main> to resize vertically with it.  The content in the <aside> will change over time. Using 'absolute' will remove it from normal flow.

Comment: Just make sure to "clear" anything below that you don't want to float next to the aside:  http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/2aefptof/5/