# Vertical align middle to an absolute positioned children

Tags: html, css

[I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941613/vertical-align-middle-and-position-absolute) looked [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472794/vertical-align-with-absolute-positioning) and I [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455100/how-to-center-div-vertically-inside-of-absolutely-positioned-parent-div) really [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919073/position-relative-and-right-property) how to solve this problem. 
Consider this little youtube search result, which brings back the thumbnail of the video, title and a small image. The vertical alignment was possible on the thumbnail and title since they are relative to the [parent](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) . However my small image needs to be placed in the middle aswell but also `right=0`. So [my soulution](https://jsfiddle.net/zh2b7apL/2/) was to make the image position absolute which resulted in it losing the vertical alignment. Or either [keep](https://jsfiddle.net/zh2b7apL/3/) the relative positioning and thus resulted in it not being placed in the right of the screen. Is there anyway I can achieve to position it in the vertical center and right?

Note that I want the list to be dynamic so set the height is not possible since it will result in more issues.

```css
.mobilItem {
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.bilden {
    border-radius: 30%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 1%;
}
.title {
   display: inline-block;
    max-width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.plus {
    vertical-align: middle; 
    cursor: pointer;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<li class="mobilItem">  
<img data-video="k2C5TjS2sh4" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg" alt="play" class="bilden" width="30%" height="30%">
 <p class="title">Roxette - It Must Have</p>
 <img src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/2x/plus--v1.png" alt="Roxette - It Must Have Been Love (Official Music Video)" class="plus" id="k2C5TjS2sh4" width="45" height="45" name="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg">
 </li>
  <li class="mobilItem">  
<img data-video="k2C5TjS2sh4" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg" alt="play" class="bilden" width="30%" height="30%">
 <p class="title">Roxette - It Must Have</p>
 <img src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/2x/plus--v1.png"  alt="Roxette - It Must Have Been Love (Official Music Video)" class="plus" id="k2C5TjS2sh4" width="45" height="45" name="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg">
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you could use `flex` as in the example snippet.

```css
.mobilItem {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: stretch;
    flex-flow: row;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2f2f2f;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.bilden {
    border-radius: 30%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 20%;
}
.title {
   display: inline-block;
    width: calc(70% - 45px);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.plus {
    width: 6%;
    cursor: pointer;
    right:0;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<li class="mobilItem">  
<img data-video="k2C5TjS2sh4" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg" alt="play" class="bilden" width="30%" height="30%">
 <p class="title">Roxette - It Must Have</p>
 <img src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/2x/plus--v1.png" alt="Roxette - It Must Have Been Love (Official Music Video)" class="plus" id="k2C5TjS2sh4" width="45" height="45" name="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg">
 </li>
  <li class="mobilItem">  
<img data-video="k2C5TjS2sh4" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg" alt="play" class="bilden">
 <p class="title">Roxette - It Must Have</p>
 <img src="https://img.icons8.com/cotton/2x/plus--v1.png"  alt="Roxette - It Must Have Been Love (Official Music Video)" class="plus" id="k2C5TjS2sh4" name="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/k2C5TjS2sh4/hqdefault.jpg">
 </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like intended!

Answer (score 0):

I use this to position centre -> right

```
.parent{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; /* can be any */
    height: 400px; /* can be any */
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: But you set hight, which was not possible